# About properties of a three dimensional tensor in the context of rotation

Tags: combinatorics, tensors, rotations

Given a three dimensional tensor T, how can I figure out:

1. How many 'fundamental' states T has? By 'fundamental' I mean states needed to derive all other possible states of the T by rotating it arbitrarily along x, y and z axis by 90° increments.
2. Given a particular state of T, how can I figure the number of different states that can be derived by rotating it?

The above is my best try at generalizing the question. Now I'm going to give a specific example.

Consider a 2x2x2 tensor holding boolean [0, 1] values. Such a tensor has $2^8$ possible states. Imagine it as a 3d cube composed of 8 cells. This cube can be rotated in euclidean space by 90° steps along any axis. Some examples:

- A uniform tensor with all values equal either 0 or 1 can not be used to derive other states by rotating it.
- The below tensor can be used to derive 7 other states
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
- The below tensor can be used to derive 11 other states
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
- The below tensor can be used to derive 3 other states
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$

PS: I would like to, in advance, apologize to any mathematicians offended by my uninformed, crude and imprecise definitions above. I'm a mere engineer, have mercy.

Comment: While there may be an interesting question here, at this point it's hard to tell what you're asking. In particular, how, precisely, do you define a "tensor", what is the set of "rotations", and how do these "rotations" act on "tensors"? In each case it seems you're referring to something very different than the standard meanings of the terms.

Comment: Also, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858310/how-many-distinct-ways-are-there-to-2-color-the-8-vertices-of-a-cube) seems to cover your special case.